# Java Code not working after Applet conversion

Tags: java, printing, applet, parallel-port

Hello and have a nice day.

I'm developing a web app and i need to use a Dot Matrix printer. The printer is using a USB port but i [followed this steps](http://www.ehow.com/how_8698428_redirect-lpt1-usb-printer.html) and i can send raw data to my printer successfully.

Here's the code:

```
package print;

import java.io.*;

public class lpt {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("LPT1");
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os);

            String text = "this is a test -- second line here --                     end";
            text = text.toUpperCase();
            String[] row = text.split("--");
            for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                int size = row[i].length();
                String line = row[i];
                if (line.endsWith("--")) {
                    line = line.substring(0, size - 1);
                }
                ps.println(line);
            }
            ps.print("\f");
            ps.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly alone, but when i migrate (change some code) to use it as an applet.

```
package print;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.io.*;

public class lpt extends Applet {

    public void init() {
        try {
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("LPT1");
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os);

            String text = "this is a test -- second line here --                     end";
            text = text.toUpperCase();
            String[] row = text.split("--");
            for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                int size = row[i].length();
                String line = row[i];
                if (line.endsWith("--")) {
                    line = line.substring(0, size - 1);
                }
                ps.println(line);
            }
            ps.print("\f");
            ps.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work on the web, i configured jnlp to use with deployJava.js but with this code it doesn't run, i need this Applet for my Web App (made in PHP) to print comprobants and tickets (yes, a sales system).
I used printerJob and Graphics class yet, but my printing goes distorted and the previous solution is better and faster.

Comment: this is the link http://www.ehow.com/how_8698428_redirect-lpt1-usb-printer.html to the USB to LPT fix

Comment: Have you signed your Applet? If not you cannot print from it. See [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) - "Sandbox applets cannot perform the following operations:" ... "They cannot access client resources such as the local filesystem, executable files, system clipboard, and **printers**."

Comment: Like i said, i made another applet to access to my printer, it worked but the font was stretched (because dot matrix need raw data, all other format are graphics)... i followed this instructions https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml and it worked, but now with this new code it can't print